# How to properly use virtual environment python on an nfs server?

Tags: nfs, virtualenv

Is it a good practice to directly invoke python binary from the virtual environment on an nfs mounted disk? Obviously this avoids installing the virtual environment on every client machine, especially if the server has multiple virtual environments. But in practice I find that there can sometimes be path related inconsistencies that are difficult to solve systematically.

The other option is to use a docker image. But I dislike that because it is pretty heavy-duty and inflexible, i.e., difficult to install or modify code, especially code in the site-packages directory directly.

So I am looking for best/proven-to-work practice in this area. Thanks!